# How to publish to Facebook fan/business pages (not user profiles)

Tags: .net, facebook

I'm trying to figure out if fan/business pages are conceptually similar to regular user pages. My end goal is to publish events from a third-party Web site (new content, announcements, etc.) into the FB page that promotes the third-party site. I'm not sure where to start exactly.

Been looking at the .NET Facebook SDK, and it seems focused on FB apps and authentication. Not sure where I should be looking.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you implementing this on the third-party site in ASP.NET? I would recommend clarifying this in your question.

Comment: Sure, what other scenario is there? I don't think the platform is really all that relevant as much as understanding if the FB API does what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is "yes", fan/business pages are conceptually similar to regular user pages. You just need to specify the id of the page instead of the user profile. Either way, you will need to get an access token to allow your application to publish to a page or profile on behalf of a specific user.

Comment: SO encourages answers to have more descriptive relative information and at best interest a code snippet if required - for better clarity.